# How to make 2 buttons toggle css with jquery and using only 1 button instead. NOT display hide/show

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement

Guys I am stuck with this issue, even using standard js I can not make it to archieve what I want.

I placed a JSfiddle where you can see in a very simple way what I am trying to do, surely it is not complete code but I tried to make it really easy to understand what I want.

I have 2 buttons and 2 different css properties. I do not want to use a toggle because in this way the concept gets lost. As it is only just a bit of a huge project of mine.`.toggle()` is not suitable here and even does not work because it displays and then makes it hidden, but in my case there must be no hidden or again displaying. Anyway, better see it rather than write a book here :)))

[My fiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/elchinsolo/1qgmbtq4/)

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".bob").click(function() {
        $(".box").css("background", "#ffffff");
        $(".box").css("transform", "rotateX(30deg)");
        $(".box").css("width", "300px");
      });
      $(".jek").click(function() {
        $(".box").removeAttr("style");
        $(".box").css("transform", "rotateY(120deg)");
      });
    })
```

Also, I want to make only 1 button to do the work of 2 buttons. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add a general class to your button, like `.button` for instance, and do this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".button").click(function () {
        var $target = $(this);
        if ($target.is('.bob')) {
            $target.removeClass('bob').addClass('jek');
            // do whatever you need for bob
        } else {
           $target.removeClass('jek').addClass('bob');
            // do whatever you need for jek
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but this also does not  fulfill my needs, i am trying to add on one element many classes i ll change my fiddle code to more complex to show info.  anyways thanks.

Answer (score 1):

same concept as @i-- without adding the button class to the button, but using the :button jquery selector, and simply toggling the class on the button click and have different css for each class. Note that if there is actually more than one button - you will need to add a class or id to the desired one (and change the js below) otherwise this will trigger the toggle on any button click...., but if theres only one button this will do the job.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(":button").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('bob jek');
    });
});
```

//css

```
.bob{//whatever css styling}
.jek{//whatever css styling}
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but it does not  fulfill my needs, i am trying to add on one element many classes i ll change my fiddle code to more complex to show info.  anyways thanks.